# Any way to make new version only for fresh installations in Android Play store?

Tags: android, google-play-services, version, google-developers-console

I have an app published with version 1.2 in Play store. Now new version 1.4 is availbale to upload. Can by any means ask play store to make 1.4 available only for fresh installation and not available for an update from 1.2 to 1.4 ?

Comment: You can change the package name and make it available

Answer (score 0):

Set the version code lower than the version numbers of 1.2 to 1.4. You can change the version code in the module level `build.gradle`.

> versionCode — An integer used as an internal version number. This number is used only to determine whether one version is more recent than another, with higher numbers indicating more recent versions. This is not the version number shown to users; that number is set by the versionName setting, below.

The purpose of the version code is to determine whether or not it is a latest one or not. If the number is lower than the other numbers then play store doesn't consider this an update to the earlier version and won't notify the users about the update.

Already installed app users won't see an update button if they open your app page but new users can download the latest version 1.4.

For more info on versioning your app take a look at [official docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html).